# Running .exe in docker locally

Tags: .net, docker

I have a very small .net console application,

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is testing!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

The path structure is like this
C:\Kubernetes\src\Sample\bin\Release
\debug

My project, dockerfile and sln file are all inside the sample folder

My dockerfile looks like this,

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016
ADD . /bin/Release
ENTRYPOINT Sample.exe
```

I build the image successfully using the following command,

```
docker build . -t samplekube:local
```

When I try to run the image locally

```
docker run samplekube:local
```

I get the following error,

```
'Sample.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I test an image that contains an .exe in the docker locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not familiar with .net but
Execution is complaining about Sample.exe is not found. You're placing the file in /bin/Release directory in the Dockerfile.
So having this line would make more sense:
ENTRYPOINT /bin/Release/Sample.exe

And also the directory path is containing unix like directory path eventhough the base image is windows server so I think the error must have come from one of those things i mentioned.

I advice you to execute shell on the Entry point to enter the container and find the location of the file

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried changing the paths but still getting the same error

Comment: have you executed a shell in the entry point to enter the container? If so, can you go to the directory /bin/Release and check if your .exe file exists?

Comment: I've been trying, but I am getting an empty console the sh script contains just chmod +x ./Sample.exe and I excecute it from the command PS C:\Kubernetes\src\Sample\bin\release> ./Sample.sh

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the late reply. I was not active on this platform. Can you go to the location like: cd C:\Kubernetes\src\Sample\bin\release>  to see the executable?